# Too many UILabels with unicode text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have 180 `UILabels` (subviews of `UITableViewCells`) in an iPad app with 155 width X 155 height for each `UILabel`, and each one contains a big amount of Unicode text (Arabic language), when I scroll down the `TableView` it hangs for 1 second and then keeps scrolling normally, this happens with every scroll attempt by the user and this is tested on iPAD2 device.

however, when I changed the text to English language (also big amount of English text), the `TableView` does not hang and scrolls normally.

anyone got an idea on how to solve this issue with Unicode text ?

thank you so much in advance.

EDIT:

the code is large to fit here, so in brief, I create each `UILabel` with a loop like this: `[[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, then play with the frame later in the same method according to interface orientation, after that I add each `UILabel` to the cell like this: `[cell.contentView addSubView:myLabel];` . each cell contains 4 of these 'UILabels', so I have a total of 45 cells, nothing more, straight forward and simple code.

Comment: I don't know the direct answer but in any case try to optimize your app that it would serve the subviews of `UITableViewCells` as quick as possible since there is another potential threat. If the user scrolls so quickly that the cell scrolls out before its content could be rendered, your whole `UITableView` will be emptied and there is no way to recover it without reloading the whole view.

Comment: the problem I guess lies within the size of the Unicode text, still couldn't find a way to reduce this size before assigning the text in to the label

Comment: Do you think creating a view with 180 labels loaded with huge texts is the best approach in responsive and uncluttered smartphone app design?

Comment: yes in the case of filling a big form with data

Comment: If you really need that many labels with that many text, it could be an idea to draw them into `UIImages` before the view loads and show the ready images from the `UITableViews`. This way you can pre-render your text (I guess this takes a lot of time) and save processing time when you need to show them.

Comment: Do you mean that you have 180 cells, each with a large UILabel as a subview, or that you have 180 UILabels as subviews of a single cell? Can you include some code to indicate how you are populating these labels? Have you done time profiling to see where the bottleneck is?

Comment: @MrTj it maybe a good idea if there were fewer number of UILabels.

Comment: @jrturton please have a look at EDIT above.

Comment: You need to include more of (if not your whole...) cellForRowAtIndexPath. Do you only create the labels for a new cell, or every time? Where do you get the text from to populate them? What are you doing with the frame that can't be done using autoresizing masks?

Comment: @jrturton , answers to your three quetions: 1) tried both but no difference. 2) I use static text (for testing) like this: myLabel.text = @"large text here"; nothing faster than a static text. 3) ALL autoresizing masks did not satisfy my view layout the way I need it to look when rotations take place, so I switched to manual frames manipulations.

Comment: Question? 1) Is there a particular reason of using UILabel instead of other objects? 2) Have you tried using UIWebView?

Comment: have you figured out on which lines of code the application hangs? if not, this is probably the first thing you should do (either debug, or put some NSLogs in the places where you think this might occur).

Comment: @jovhenni19 I have tried UIWebView, it's really much slower than the UILabel. thank you anyway for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The use of unicode shouldn't be the problem here, as it will render at similar speeds to any other text.

There are possibly a few issues that are slowing down your code. First of all, you should attempt to use UITableView's native cell reuse, add the labels to the UITableViewCell and then dequeueWithResusableIdentifier them. You should only generate your labels when that method returns nil and you have to create a new UITableViewCell (it's unclear from the original question if you do this already).

One other thing you can do after this to make sure as many of your views are opaque as possible to speed up compositing. Instruments includes an option to tint non-opaque views to make this easier.

Comment: dequeueWithResusableIdentifier has been used but without any marked difference, and as i mentioned in the question the tableView scrolls normally when text is English, and abnormally when the text is Unicode

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can optimize your code:

One check if your app is not leaking. Proper release of labels.
Use reusability of cells. I dont know if you are using that or not. 
Since every time you scroll your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method is called.

[In case you dont know about reusability try this link.](http://www.iphonedeveloperdiary.com/2010/03/correct-use-of-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-in-a-table-view-on-the-iphone/)

Comment: I have used dequeueReusableCell without any benefit in this case

Comment: The allocation of memory will be much faster than the actual repainting.

Comment: can u show me your code. Since loading multiple images can be optimized to some extent, so we can optimize loading text in labels

Comment: as i mentioned in the question, the code is huge and can't be fit here.

Comment: U can use pastebin for that... See without code we can't fire bullets in air.. What we mention is then just suggestions. If you post code, we will be able to help you in better ways.