# UITableView's reloadData for all rows

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

Is there a possible way to call (or customize) `reloadData` method to let the table view to reload data for all of its rows (not only the visible ones) ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems very unlikely since the table view expects to reuse cells during scrolling.  In a very real sense, many of the "rows" that aren't visible don't even exist.  What's your higher-level purpose in wanting this (...maybe there's a different approach)?

Comment: @phillipMills Im thinking of a workaround to my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989495/too-many-uilabels-with-unicode-text   in a brief, I got some hangs during the FIRST scrolling of my table view when it contains a lot of labels with unicode text in each label, Im pretty sure my code is clean and there is no single memory leak or glitches out there, so I decided to add an ActivityIndicator view when the table view calls its reloadData for the first time, and then let the table view to reload all data in all rows, then stopping that indicator view after some notification.

Comment: I am very confident you need to figure our what you are doing wrong in implementing both "reusable cells" as well as "fetching the data". If you post your code maybe people can comment on that, specially you want to post 'cellforrowatindexpath' as well as whatever you use to fill fetchresultscontroller.

Comment: or tell us how large your dataset is?

Comment: 45 cells with 4 UILabels (of size 55 X 55) in each cell, each UILabel got a big amount of unicode text.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to customize reloadData. As mentioned, the cells that are off screen don't actually exist. They're sitting in a reuse queue (hopefully), waiting to be pulled on screen. Once they are going to move on screen, the table view sends tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: to its data source. Here, you configure all of the stuff you want on that particular cell, for that particular row.

You may want to consider creating an array that holds the data for your cells. So, if you have 100 cells-worth of data, create an array with 100 items in it. If only cells 10-15 are visible, but you need to update the data that will be displayed in cell 89, simply access the 89th element of the array, and update it appropriately. Once you scroll down to the 89th cell, you just access the array at the indexPath.row.

Answer (score 1):

those rows that are not visible are not even there! I mean there is no cells beside the visible ones plus one or two more on the edges.
So I guess your answer would be no there is no way to do that or you need to explain more why you need to do this!

Comment: look at my comment above please.

Answer (score 0):

[tableView reloadData] does only refresh the visible cells. The data of the cells should be separated of the tableview and you could reload it by creating a method that e.g. reloads the internal array of items that contains the data presented in the cells.